# Error when I am trying to install VirtualBox-6.1(secure boot On)

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualbox, homestead, ubuntu-20.04

I am getting this error when I am trying to install VirtualBox-6.1. I cannot turn off the secure boot.
I am installing Virtual box for I want to use [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/homestead)

```
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-6.1_6.1.18-142142_Ubuntu_eoan_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.18-142142~Ubuntu~eoan) over (6.1.18-142142~Ubuntu~eoan) ...
Setting up virtualbox-6.1 (6.1.18-142142~Ubuntu~eoan) ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
```

I have tried the solution by [majal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur).
I am using ubuntu 20.04.2
Output of `uname -r` is `5.8.0-44-generic`
Please Help.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to install the *virtualbox-dkms* package

**sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms**